# How can I use "The Old Reader" on Android?

Tags: rss

[The Old Reader](http://theoldreader.com) is so far my best replacement for Google Reader.

Is there a way to use it on Android, for example an RSS app that syncs with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Old Reader's website has a [list of apps](http://theoldreader.com/pages/apps) that are known to use its API. The only Android app currently listed is: [Listener Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.piaci.listener.app) which is an alternative Launcher, so probably does more than you want.

However a quick search of the Play Store for ["the old reader"](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=%22the%20old%20reader%22&c=apps) comes up with: [The Old Reader (unofficial)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.toreaderapp) app, and the [gReader (free version)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.noinnion.android.greader.reader) ([paid version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.noinnion.android.greader.readerpro)) app both of which claim to sync with The Old Reader, amongst other services.

Comment: I searched on the play store and didn't find them ... odd. Thanks!

Comment: @ripper234 with the Google Reader apocalypse happening right now I'm guessing there's a lot of RSS apps putting out new versions over the last few days with alternate back-ends. Both of those apps have had new versions pushed to the Play Store in the last 48 hours, so it might be that there really weren't any results when you searched, but there are now!